# How to perform integration tests for an Angular-based application in production?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, integration-testing

I am trying to add integration testing to my Angular 10 based application and everything seems to be working properly locally. I just define the tests in files with the spec.ts extension and run using ng test. The question is how can I run these tests in production? I use GitLab CI to dockerize application and to run in production using nginx on Kubernetes. So when I access my pod there is built production version and of course ng test does not work. I just need to run tests mainly related to my Angular service with some example requests like POST, GET, DELETE etc. to other components to check whether the whole system is working properly with Angular portal. Do you have any ideas how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`ng test` is for unit and integration tests and I don't think it makes sense to run these tests in `production`.

I think what you are looking for is E2E (End to End)/AT (Acceptance Testing) testing and you can use `WebDriverIO, Cypress, Protractor` for these. E2E testing will actually open up a browser, navigate to your URL of your application and start using the application like a superman human.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7N63cMKosIE) can be a good start for you.